# add all active users to a chatter group

Tags: apex, error-messages

I am trying to add all active users in our org to a specific chatter group using the anonymous window, but I get this error message saying

> Line: 7, Column: 20 Variable does not exist: id" not sure what I am
> doing wrong.

Any suggestions please?

```apex
list <user> u = [select id from user where IsActive = true];

CollaborationGroup n = [select id from CollaborationGroup where Name = 'Navy Chatter Group'];

list <CollaborationGroupMember> groupMembers = new list <CollaborationGroupMember>();
for (CollaborationGroupMember g : groupMembers){
    g.MemberId = u.id; 
    g.CollaborationGroupId = n.id;
    groupMembers.add(g);
}
insert groupMembers;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you get error messages with a line #, you always want to focus on why it would say that line. Is it actually that line, or a missing semicolon on the line before, etc. It's essentially the first step

In this case it's throwing it on line 7 which is this line

```apex
g.MemberId = u.id;
```

The next thing is the message itself

> Variable does not exist: id

That seems pretty self-explanatory - so this message is calling out that `id` doesn't exist which you're using specifically in `u.id`.

The next question is: why does `id` not exist on my variable `u`? Working backwards, you have to check what is `u`. In your code

```apex
 list <user> u = [select id from user where IsActive = true];
```

So `u` is a `List<User>`. Looking at [Lists](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_collections_lists.htm)

> A **list is an ordered collection of elements** that are distinguished by
> their indices. List elements can be of any data type—primitive types,
> collections, sObjects, user-defined types, and built-in Apex types.

Which means the variable `u` could contain multiple users records.

| Index 0 | Index 1 | Index 2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Contact1 | Contact2 | Contact3 |

This should help illuminate your issue - you can't reference a field (`id`) from a user record when you're not working on the specific record.

You'll want to go through your list (so you're on a user record) and then reference the user field.

However, even if you fix that, your code is not currently doing anything. What you're currently doing is:

- Query active users
- Get a CollaborationGroup
- Create an empty list of CollaborationGroupMembers
- Loop through an empty list (nothing to loop for)
- insert an empty list (nothing will happen)

If you want to create a `CollaborationGroupMember` for every user for the identified group, you need to loop through the list that actually has records (users). You'll loop through each user, create a `CollaborationGroupMember` record related to them, add that record to a list (to support insert all the records at once), and then insert the list.

```apex
List<User> users = [select id from user where IsActive = true];
CollaborationGroup collaborationGroup = [select id from CollaborationGroup where Name = 'Navy Chatter Group'];
//to store all the records you'll be creating and insert
List<CollaborationGroupMember> groupMembers = new List<CollaborationGroupMember>();

for(User u : users){
    CollaborationGroupMember groupMember = new CollaborationGroupMember();
    groupMember.MemberId = u.id;
    ...
    groupMembers.add(groupMember);
}


insert groupMembers;
```

*Things to watch out for:*

- When you [query expecting one record](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000328824&type=1), it'll throw an error if no records are returned. In this case, if there's no group called exactly `Navy Chatter Group`, then it will throw

> List has no rows for assignment to SObject

- Variable names - I renamed your lists to be plural (`users` vs. `u`, `collaborationGroup` vs. `n`). Unclear variable names make code difficult to understand - especially when it's a single letter that's unrelated to what it contains.
- Depending on the context of this code, your user query could run into issues in large orgs or those with large amounts of community users. There's [limits](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet.meta/salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet/salesforce_app_limits_platform_apexgov.htm) to the number of records you can return (50,000) you need to be aware of so you want to be specific to your needs (internal only, community only, or both).

`SELECT Id FROM Users WHERE UserType = 'Standard'`;

Comment: Thank you for all those suggestions. I am new to the programing and hungry to learn from great people like yourself. I appreciated all those recommendations and will definitely add them to my tool box.

Answer (score 0):

This works perfect... without cross reference error

```
trigger addMemGroup on User (after insert) {
List<User> users = [SELECT Id FROM User WHERE IsActive = true ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC LIMIT 1];
CollaborationGroup collaborationGroup = [SELECT Id FROM CollaborationGroup WHERE Name = 'Support Group test' LIMIT 1];

if(collaborationGroup != null){
    List<CollaborationGroupMember> groupMembers = new List<CollaborationGroupMember>();

    for(User u : users){
        CollaborationGroupMember groupMember = new CollaborationGroupMember();
        groupMember.MemberId = u.Id;
        groupMember.CollaborationGroupId = collaborationGroup.Id;
        groupMembers.add(groupMember);
    }

    insert groupMembers;
}
```

}